# Space between elements using `Write`

Tags: export, output-formatting, output, writing

I have the code:

```
ss = OpenAppend["/home/mateus/LaminarSeparationBubble/RD/Dados/teste.dat"];
Do[Write[ss, N[i], N[i]], {i, 1, 10}];
Close["/home/mateus/LaminarSeparationBubble/RD/Dados/teste.dat"];
```

My output file is in the form:

```
1.1.
2.2.
3.3.
4.4.
5.5.
6.6.
7.7.
8.8.
9.9.
10.10.
```

How to add space between the elements in the same line?
Like this:

```
1.  1.
2.  2.
3.  3.
4.  4.
5.  5.
6.  6.
7.  7.
8.  8.
9.  9.
10. 10.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `WriteString` function instead of `Write`:

```
ss = OpenWrite[$TemporaryDirectory <> "/test.dat"];
Do[
  WriteString[ss, N[i], " ", N[i], "\n"],
  {i, 1, 10}
  ];
Close[$TemporaryDirectory <> "/test.dat"];

Import[$TemporaryDirectory <> "/test.dat", "Text"]

(* Out:
    "1. 1.
    2. 2.
    3. 3.
    4. 4.
    5. 5.
    6. 6.
    7. 7.
    8. 8.
    9. 9.
    10. 10." *)
```